# Different results in Databricks using SARIMAX

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, sarimax

In Databricks, using 11.3 ML runtime give different results when using general purpose vs memory-optimized workers. I used SARIMAX and to forecast the results but I’m getting different results when I change the driver and worker types to this options. Does anyone know why am I getting this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting different results when using General purpose vs memory-optimized workers in Databricks while using SARIMAX for forecasting.

The reasons could be:

Computing power General purpose workers are designed to handle a wide variety of workloads. However memory-optimized workers are optimized for memory-intensive workloads.
Because of this lead to better performance for memory-intensive algorithms like SARIMAX.

Memory-optimized workers are better when compared to general purpose when connecting to the network this also can lead to data transfer faster with the Memory-optimized workers

Memory-optimized workers have large memory than the general purpose workers.

Please consider these too and check.

Make sure that your code is the same when running on both general purpose and memory-optimized workers.
Differences in code could also could lead to differences in results.

Look for the logs and metrics for each run to see if there are any differences in the resources used, such as CPU and memory utilization.

Try Using the SARIMAX On smaller dataset and check if the results are same as before.
If the issue is still persisting then the issue is in configuration or set up of your data bricks environments.